# JS backward string interpolation

Tags: javascript, parsing, config, string-interpolation, destruction

I'm going to parse a big custom-formed config from txt to class, adjust it in Form and then save it back. Saving is not a problem, I can use Interpolation and this is awesome.

After this, I just wondered if I can do a backward interpolation, like the destruction of text file content.

So I can get values '1','Boing','green' from this config

```
1; 0=BMW,1=Volvo
boing;
green;
```

like this

```
{car}; 0=BMW,1=Volvo
{plane};
{color};
```

UPD: It's just an example, and Parsing of this one takes time. Real file has about 1K lines

Comment: so split on new lines and split each line on semi colon.

Comment: Or use a regular expression.

Comment: @epascarello, yes, that's what I did, but I'm just trying to figure out whether there is a way to do it diffrently

Comment: @Barmar I'm thinking about it, but it's a reserve plan for me, thanks

Comment: You can, but if you go down that rabbit hole, you'll find a lot of edge cases you want to solve and take it further and further. Reverse interpolation can be quite complicated, [I know](https://github.com/zuze-lab/interpolate)

Comment: @Adam, oh, looks like It worth it at least to have a one-eye look
Thank you for the link

Comment: If you can depend on a reasonably recent JavaScript, you could use [named capture groups](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-named-groups), introduced in 2018. It's a bit more punctuation than your ideal, but a lot more flexible.

Comment: @rici thank you, I will have a look at it too!